# wifi problem,wifi-hardware-switch, madwifi

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch, madwifi

i dont see wifi, no conected-in my macbook pro Mid 2012 processor 2.5 ghz dual-core intel core i5 ram 4G

no encuentro el wifi solo me puedo conectar con cable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)